# JBOSS EAP 6.3.GA ILLEGAL SHUTDOWN ISSUE

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

I am using JBOSS EAP 6.3.GA on CentOs with open JDK 6 64 bit.

Previously, I started the JBOSS in standalone mode and it was working well.
Now, I was trying to start JBOSS in domain mode with 1 server only. It was working fine but after 20-30 mintues it shutdown itself with no error printing in log file.

I am unable to find what causes the error. 
Need help.

Comment: Do the logs show it being shutdown? Is there a JVM log?

Comment: Yes, JBOSS server logs shows shutdown call for all services with no error.

Comment: I'd guess either something is sending a `SIGINT` to the process or someone is sending a `shutdown` command.